# working with spaces in for /f batch commands

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, space

Suppose to have a file named dir.txt with the following content:

```
singleword
two words
```

Running the dos batch command

```
for /f %%d in (dir.txt) do echo %%d
```

displays

```
singlewords
two
```

that is the second row is truncated to the first space. How to force the command to return the entire row contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while `tokens=*` removes leading spaces better use `delims=`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%d in (dir.txt) do echo %%d
```

Note: this removes all empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in (dir.txt) do echo %%d
```

Or if you don't want all of them for some reason:

```
for /f %%d in (dir.txt) do echo %%d %%e
```